# Get maximum touch event size for a device?

Tags: android, dynamic, touch, motion

How do I get access to the values of `InputDevice.MotionRange getMotionRange(int axis)`, so I can find the maximum acceptable size of a touchEvent on a given phone?

**[edit]**
To clarify, I'm looking to pair the results of `MotionEvent.getSize()` (1f being the largest acceptable touch event area) with a function that will actually tell me this property of the phone? Thus getting an approximate size in px/dips whatever of the touch area.

Basically trying to do something like below:

```
final InputDevice device = event.getDevice();
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

There are different values for different touch events. The best place to start is the [ViewConfiguration](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewConfiguration.html) class, specifically the fields which have "slop" in their name. If you want to know how far your finger has to move to be classed as a scroll event, you would use `getScaledTouchSlop()`; and if you wanted to know the maximum permissible distance between two taps for them to register as a double tap, you would use `getScaledDoubleTapSlop()`.

You can obtain the `ViewConfiguration` for any given `Context` by calling:

```
ViewConfiguration vc = ViewConfiguration.get( context );
```

Comment: absolutely great information in this class that I wasn't actually looking for. Thank you for the information regardless. Basically I'm looking to pair the results of MotionEvent.getSize() with a value that will indicate it's maximum size when it records 1f as a max touchEvent?

Comment: Does the information in `InputDevice.MotionRange` help you at all?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm asking how to get access to? I can't seem to get access to the function/constants within this class.

Comment: How about `InputDevice. getDevice( motionEvent. getDeviceId() ). getMotionRange() `?